# XML input for Powershell Function

Tags: powershell, optimization, xmldocument

I have an XML which has multiple nodes and sub-nodes from which am consuming data as input for multiple functions from the main function.

I have a basic question on optimized code here.

1. Is it good to pass the XML object as an input to multiple function which consumes some data from the XML?
2. Is it good to pass the XML path to the function and instantiate XML object inside each function?
3. Is there a way to pass just the node which is required for a particular function? ( In-case i have 10 nodes and 10 functions - where each function requires just one particular node for consuming data)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that it's better to pass only specific arguments to each function. The less broad your input, the simpler your input validation. Also, I'd strongly recommend to avoid repeatedly reading/parsing the same data. There's no benefit at all in doing that.